# Bottled and right into the fridge

Tags: bottle-conditioning, secondary-fermentation

I added sugar, bottled, then put them into the fridge instead of leaving them at 68-76 degrees for a week. What should I do now, or is it too late to save the batch?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to worry about "saving" the batch.  Even if you left them in the fridge they'd still carb, just very slowly.  It might take months.  But there's absolutely nothing wrong with taking them out of the fridge for a couple weeks to carb, then returning them to the fridge once the process is complete.

Comment: Nope just read the tips for cold lagering and skipped over reading the step about room temperature for a week after bottling! Thanks for your input -I carried the bottles upstairs to allow them to carbonate.

Answer (score 3):

The yeast will still carbonate at fridge temperatures; just very slowly. Think months instead of weeks.

I presume you put the beer in the fridge as you want to start trying to drink them. My advice would be to take your beer out of the fridge, and let them warm up to room temperature (65-75 degrees), and just stick them in a closet for a a few weeks. If you decide you want to try one to see how the beer is carbonating or maturing, just pop a bottle in the fridge a few hours before you plan to consume it.

Depending on the style of beer you have made, you may want to allow your beer longer or shorter time to condition prior to drinking it.

Comment: Nope just read the tips for cold lagering and skipped over reading the step about room temperature for a week after bottling! Thanks for your input -I carried the bottles upstairs to allow them to carbonate.